# How to optimize this query more?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

```
    SELECT mem.name, 
           mem.regdate, 
           stat.level
      FROM stats AS stat
INNER JOIN members AS mem
     WHERE stat.id = mem.id 
       AND mem.ref = {$members['id']}
```

`stats` and `members` table has index on `id`. But when I run query it checks all rows in `stats` table (in `members` table it takes only one). Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use correct ANSI-92 JOIN syntax - JOIN criteria is specified in the ON clause:

```
SELECT mem.name, 
       mem.regdate, 
       stat.level
  FROM stats AS stat
  JOIN members AS mem ON mem.id = stat.id 
 WHERE mem.ref = {$members['id']}
```

Without the JOIN criteria, MySQL will return a cartesian product and then apply the WHERE clause to those results.  Pretty much any other database would tell you that you have a syntax error for the query you provided.

Also, the `INNER` keyword is optional.

Comment: That's what happens when you don't program a few weeks... Thanks

Comment: It still checks all `stats` rows, what it could be?

Comment: @hey: The `id` column is the primary key for the respective table, right?  The CREATE TABLE statements, and EXPLAIN PLAN output would help.

Comment: If I add this to where clause: `AND stat.id = 35`, then it checks only one row in both tables, so every index is put right.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting from the main table (in this case members, I persume) and JOIN with stats for additional information. Use ON to define how stats is connected to members, and use WHERE to limit the results from the member table.

```
SELECT mem.name, mem.regdate, stat.level
FROM members AS mem
INNER JOIN stats AS stat
  ON stat.id = mem.id
WHERE mem.ref = {$members['id']}
```

Since it's an INNER JOIN you can turn it around as well (selecting from stats, joining on members), but this probably makes more sense given you're looking at a certain member.